# Chart Missing Observations

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I'm having trouble with a combination chart.  I'm using the old-school chart because same vis in the Legacy Visualizations and New Visualizations forces a second values axis with a different scale on the right.  I don't want that.

The trouble I'm having is that not all of the observations are showing up.  I have a page with a chart and a list.  Both use the same query, but some observations are missing from the chart.

[image: Chart Missing Observations]

`[MATSLabNumberNumeric] = cast ( substring ( [MATS Lab Number], 6 ), int )` where MATS Lab Number is like FA0200088 (for the first observation in the list).  All observations are displayed if the MATS Lab Number is used, but not if MATSLabNumberNumeric is used.

I tried resizing the chart, but as expected, changing the layout had no effect on the data being presented.  It just made the columns wider or narrower.

I have had the same results in all combinations of these:
Cognos Analytics 11.0.13
Cognos Analytics 11.1.7
Interactive Viewer
Compatible Viewer
11.4 styles
10.x styles
combination chart
bar chart
column chart
area chart
line chart

Any idea what could be causing this?  Is there a property I inadvertently flipped?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adjusting the width of the chart under the Size and Overflow property.